# using |DataDirectory| in connectionstring of multiproject solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, multi-project, datadirectory

I have 2 projects in the solution - one class library with entities for database (using EF), one for Winforms.

Connection string is in `app.config` of the Winforms application, and it works correctly:

```
<add name="LibraryContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyLibrary.mdf;Integrated Security=True; "
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

But when I try to provide migrations, I get an error:

> A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '\MyLibrary.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

When I provide full path in connection string, everything works fine. I assume the problem is in `DataDirectory`. The project with entities for database doesn't see it or maybe see it as own `DataDirectory` and not the one for startup project (Winforms).

Please, help me to provide correct relative path for database.

Comment: You do the migrations in the data access assembly, it requires an app.config of its own for that.

Comment: but it works when I have full path for database in WinForms project

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will works.

Go to Property of project check setting tab. If you contain more then one connection string then remove it. and add connection string which you have in app config.

Thanks.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: didn't help when the path contains |DataDirectory|, only full path works.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's a suggestion at best, which should be a comment.